# How do you change ansible_default_ipv4?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'd like to change ansible_default_ipv4 to point to eth1 instead of eth0.  Can I do this in either the playbook or via the --extra-vars option?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[ansible uses command](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.16.2/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/network/linux.py#L108-L111) `ip -4 route get 8.8.8.8` to get the default ipv4 interface. You can [**change your ip/routing tables**](http://linux-ip.net/html/basic-changing.html#basic-changing-default) to make `eth1` the default route and it'll return it.

Or you can **use a** [**custom fact**](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.4/custom_facts.html#adding-custom-facts-to-facter).

PS: using `set_fact` to *override* the `ansible_default_ipv4` fact, but it has it's own pitfalls due to caching, scope, ...

Comment: I made a task that added a default gateway to /etc/sysconfig/network and restarts the network, that did the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: In case your default route is not negotiable, it is possible to override the route to 8.8.8.8 specifically:  `sudo route add -net 8.8.8.8 netmask 255.255.255.255 eth1`

Answer (score 6):

Another option is always reference your interface explicitly.
Different cloud providers have different conventions weather to put the private (usually 10.x.y.z) management network on eth0 or eth1.

Instead of referencing

```
ansible_default_ipv4["address"]
```

You can always define the iface you want (say in group_vars/all)

iface: eth0

and reference it in tasks as

{{ 'ansible_'+iface['ipv4']['address'] }}

A simple grep will show you all references.  A global find and replace on your project will let you change this.
    `grep -RH ansible_default_ipv4 .`

Then when you want to switch cloud providers you simply adapt the iface as needed.

If you prefer something less verbose, and more explicit define

```
private_iface: eth0  #switch eth0,eth1 depending on your provider.
public_iface: eth1
private_host_ipv4: "{{ 'ansible_'+private_iface['ipv4']['address'] }}"
public_host_ipv4: "{{ 'ansible_'+public_iface['ipv4']['address'] }}"
```

and only use

ansible_default_ipv4

when you want to refer to either private or public ip that would be used to get to 8.8.8.8 (the internet in general).

BTW, i tried Eron Wright's suggestion for route add -net 8.8.8.8 netmask 255.255.255.255 eth1.  It didn't seem to work for me, and i was unable to ping google (though pinging any other public ip worked).

Comment: This did not work for me as it tried to index into the string itself. According to the Ansible [FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html) you need to specify as {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_' + iface]['ipv4']['address'] }}

Answer (score 2):

`ip -4 route get 8.8.8.8` was not working on my server.

I created this work around.

`- name: find default ipv4... this is a bit of a hack.
  shell: ifconfig $(route | grep default | awk '{print $(NF)}') | grep 'inet' | awk '{ print $2}'
  register: ipv4_address`

Now I can use `ipv4_address` wherever needed!

Comment: Neither `ifconfig` nor `route` are installed by default on modern Linux systems, unless some legacy application requests them, since they are obsolete. You should be prepared for their absence.

Comment: `ip address show $(ip r | grep default | awk '{print $(NF)}') | grep 'inet' | awk '{ print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1`