# openshift_set_node_ip deprecated in openshift 3.11, what should be used instead?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

There is openshift-origin cluster version 3.11. (upgraded from 3.9)
I want to add two new nodes to cluster.

Node Hosts created in openstack project with nat, and use internal network class C (192.168.xxx.xxx), also there are floating ip attached to hosts
There are dns records which resolve fqdn of hosts to floating ips and back.
Scaleup playbook works fine but new nodes appear in cluster with their internal ips and thus nothing works.

In openshift v3.9 and earlier i used in my inventory variable 
openshift_set_node_ip = true

and point openshift_ip for adding node.

Now it doesn't work.

What should i use instead of openshift_set_node_ip?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I solved after reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/29496135 where Kashyap explain how to change the ansible_default_ipv4 fact used to guess the IP address to use.

This variable is created testing a call to 8.8.8.8 (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/e41f1a4d7d8d7331bd338a62dcd880ffe27fc8ea/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/network/linux.py#L64). You can then add a specific route to 8.8.8.8 to change the ansible_default_ipv4 fact result:

```
sudo ip r add 8.8.8.8 via YOUR_RIGHT_GATEWAY
```

Maybe it could help to solve your case.